# Why it is not adding class to the specified element

Tags: jquery

I have got an temparray with values as

```
826_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab1_checkbox
826_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab2_checkbox
```

In the above

tab1 referes to the first quantity and tab2 referes to the second quantity respectively

This is my program

```
var addonsQtyWrap = $('<div class="addonsQtyWrap"></div>');
 var temparray = [];
 var vendoritemsdata = [{
     "name": "826_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab1_checkbox",
     "cost": 100,
     "additionname": "Choco chips",
     "addtionid": 59
 }, {
     "name": "826_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab2_checkbox",
     "cost": 100,
     "additionname": "Choco chips",
     "addtionid": 59
 }];

 var quantity = 3;
 var ulhtml = '<ul>';
 for (var i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) {
     if (i == 1) {
         ulhtml += '<li    data-tabid="' + i + '"   class="tabclcik">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
     } else {

         ulhtml += '<li   data-tabid="' + i + '" class="tabclcik">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
     }
 };
 addonsQtyWrap.append(ulhtml);
 $("#header").append(addonsQtyWrap);
 for (var j = 0; j < vendoritemsdata.length; j++) {
     temparray.push(vendoritemsdata[j].name)
 }
 for (var k = 0; k < vendoritemsdata.length; k++) {
     var name = vendoritemsdata[k].name;
     alert(name);
    var res = name.indexOf("tab" + k);
        if (res !== -1) {
         $(".addonsQtyWrap").find('.tabclcik[data-tabid="'+k+'"]').addClass('active');
     }
 }
```

After creating , at the end i am checking the name of the temp array and if the name contains the tab quantity i am adding a class

But it is not  adding class active to the quantity (inspect element)

```
<li data-tabid="1" class="tabclcik">Qty-1</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/24/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing for `vendoritemsdata` starts from 0 while your `data-tabid` attributes start from `1`. I guess this is why you are not getting what you expect.

You have to solve this mismatch and to do so you have several options. For example change `tab1 -> tab0` etc. or use the `k+1` rather than `k` in your `for` cycle:

```
 var res = name.indexOf("tab" + (k+1));
```

and

```
$(".addonsQtyWrap").find('.tabclcik[data-tabid="'+(k+1)+'"]').addClass('active');
```